# Cannot restart RabbitMQ Service on Windows

Tags: port, windows-service, rabbitmq

I stopped RabbitMQ for a short time on my Windows (2012) server.  However, when I tried to restart it, it would shut down again within about 30 seconds.

The Windows Event Log had the following message:

> RabbitMQ: Erlang machine voluntarily stopped. The service is not restarted as OnFail is set to ignore.

The RabbitMQ error log had the following message:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 12-Aug-2013::13:16:59 ===
** Generic server rabbit_web_dispatch_registry terminating 
** Last message in was {add,rabbit_mgmt,
                            [{port,15672}],
                            #Fun<rabbit_web_dispatch.1.31447083>,
                            #Fun<rabbit_mgmt_app.2.5043001>,
                            {[],"RabbitMQ Management"}}
** When Server state == undefined
** Reason for termination == 
** {could_not_start_listener,[{port,15672}],eaddrinuse}
```

However, I know that there is very little running on the machine, and nothing else should be trying to bind to that port.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `netstat -ab` can be used to see what program is using each port. (Note that these arguments are only for Windows.  The similar linux command would be `netstat -lp`.  Both platforms require the user to be an administrator to execute these commands.)

In this case, I had left a Google Chrome window open to the RabbitMQ management console (`http://localhost:15672/`) and Chrome was somehow keeping the port in use.  After I closed the browser tab, I was able to start RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 3):

If you reinstall RabbitMQ and have issues running it as a windows service, a workaround could be the following:

In cmd.exe, run from the rabbit sbin folder:

```
rabbitmq-service.bat remove
rabbitmq-service.bat install
net start rabbitmq
```

It worked for me on windows 7.

Comment: That may be true, but it has absolutely nothing to do with this question.  This question says nothing about reinstalling RabbitMQ.

Comment: True, actually what I meant to say is that "if you get errors from rabbit service, after stopping it and then it fails to start, for instance, and somehow opt for a re install, but then get errors from Erlang machine, then..." I think that, at least on Win7, because of some admin privileges, nothing but the above commands seemed to be putting rabbit service back on track.

Answer (score 0):

Stop RabbitMQ Services, got to C:\RabbitMQ\rabbit@XXXXXX-mnesia\ folder. 
If the file ***recovery.dets*** is 0kb, backup and delete it, then restart RabbitMQ. This should recreate a new ***recovery.dets*** which is 6kb or more in size.